# Dimension mismatch error in R

Tags: r

Below are some variables for a data set I have. Some of them say [1:9969,1] and others just say [1:9969]. The ones with the [,1] showed up after I used the `scale` function to put all my variables to the same scale for a multilevel model I am trying to run with JAGS.

```
 $ lnlaggdpPv2      : num [1:9969, 1] 1.05 1.05 1.05 1.05 1.05 ...
 ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 18.9
 ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 1.58
 $ lnlaggdpTv2      : num [1:9969, 1] 2.556 -0.122 -0.377 1.16 -0.294 ...
 ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 17.2
 ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 1.72
 $ NoBust_sq        : num [1:9969] 0.196 0 0.009 0 0 ...
 $ NoBust_cb        : num [1:9969] 2.744 0 0.027 0 0 ...
 $ CountryID        : num [1:9969] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ YearID           : num [1:9969] 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 ...
```

Below is the command I ran that "caused" the problem:

```
pvars2 <- c("lndist","NoBust", "duration", "lagtradeshareEU", "lagtradeopenPv2", "lagtradesharePTv3", "lnlaggdpPv2", "lnlaggdpTv2",     "DefPactTP")
bustsc2 <- bust.datjags2
bustsc2[pvars2] <- lapply(bustsc2[pvars2],scale)
```

I have scoured Google, but I am not sure how to fix the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated? I hope I have explained my problem sufficiently. I'm not exactly "new" to R, but I have only begun to use it with frequency, and I am still unfamiliar with some of the intricacies.

Comment: Try `lapply(bustsc2[pvars2], function(x) as.numeric(scale(x)))`\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `scale` applied on a `vector` is a `matrix` with one column.

```
scale(1:10)
```

That explains, why we have a different output only for those columns that were `scale`d when compared to others.  The option would be to convert it to `vector` with `as.vector` or `c` or even `as.numeric`

```
bustsc2[pvars2] <- lapply(bustsc2[pvars2], function(x) as.vector(scale(x)))
```